# Change RecordType of Object from Anonymous window

Tags: apex

Trying to change record type of lead using the following code:

```
Lead l = [select Id, RecordType.Id from Lead where Id = '00Qj000000BWVSY']
RecordType r = [select Id from RecordType where Name = 'org lead 2'];
system.debug(l.RecordType.Id);
l.RecordType.Id = r.Id;
update l;
System.debug(l.RecordType.Id);
```

Debug is working fine and the second debug shows the updated record type,
but when I run the following code again,
I see that the record type is not changed.

```
Lead l = [select Id, RecordType.Id from Lead where Id = '00Qj000000BWVSY'];
System.debug(l.RecordType.Id);
```

Both record types are active and since I created both record types
and I am a system admin, I do have the privileges.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any workflow rules or triggers that set the record type based on certain criteria? It is possible that even though the record type is changed first but gets overwritten in a WF rule or Trigger.

Comment: I checked that and see no workflow rule.  I tried this in new developer org and still the record type is not being changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because you are selecting RecordType.Id instead of RecordTypeId from the Lead. So essentially, you are attempting to reassign the Id of the RecordType itself, then updating the Lead with (effectively) no changes.

It should work out if you just fix that query, and change the 4th line to `l.recordtypeid = r.id;`